# AttributeError __aexit__ when using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-telegram-bot

I have a script that should send an image to a telegram channel but I am getting the error message `AttributeError __aexit__`. I am new to asyncio library and I am trying to understand what is going on but I have no idea what the problem could be.

This is the current script I am trying to run:

```
import sys
import asyncio
import telegram

async def main():
    bot = telegram.Bot("TOKEN")
    chat_id = "CHANNEL"
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    caption = sys.argv[2]

    async with bot:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open(filename, 'rb'), caption=caption)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I was using this documentation: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API

I am using python-telegram-bot version 13.11.

Note: TOKEN and CHANNEL should be replaced with the API token and channel respectively.

I was previously using the a script without asyncio and it ran without any problem. Unfortunately other user could not use this script because it said that this was a concurrent code and it had be awaited. This is the old script (working for only some users):

```
import sys
import telegram

bot = telegram.Bot("TOKEN")
chat_id = "CHANNEL"
filename = sys.argv[1]
caption = sys.argv[2]

bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open(filename, 'rb'), caption=caption)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using version 13.x of the library, but using `telegram.Bot` with `asyncio` (e.g. as an async context manager, `async with bot:`) is only supported since version 20.x, see: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0#asyncio

You need to upgrade the library you are using or refer to the documentation of the older version, which has a different interface: https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.11/